# Как эффективней реализовать случайную генерацию математического выражения и его расчёт?

Tags: java, алгоритм, оптимизация, математика, рефакторинг

Мне зависимо от уровня сложности нужно реализовать генерацию соответствующего математического выражения (4-7+5 или 100/5*3-2+4), чтобы пользователь в игре вводил ответ и ему показывало правильно ли он посчитал. 
Как сделал я? Для каждого уровня сложности я создал свой класс (NoviceExpression, EasyExpression итп), в них создал поля, которым присваиваются результаты методов случайной генерации операторов и операндов (для операнда это случайное число от 0 до 9, для оператора это случайный элемент массива, в котором операторы хранятся в виде строки). Так же в классе есть поле, которое сохраняет результат вычисления сгенерированного выражения. Так вот, чтобы посчитать это выражение, я с помощью switch/case прохожу по операторам выражения и в зависимости от выбора считаю конкретное выражение (если конечно больше нету операторов в этом выражении) или иду к следующему оператору и опять тот же шаг с switch/case. Проще говоря - у меня это все реализовано прямым перебором и чем сложнее выражение, тем больше вложенности и размера кода. Мне это очень не нравится, хоть и работает. Возможно есть какой алгоритм для более простой и эффективной генерации выражения и его вычисления?

Это пример класса, который генерирует выражение из трех операндов и двух операторов.

```
    public class EasyExpression {
    Random random = new Random();
    private int firstTerm = generateFirstTerm();
    private int secondTerm = generateSecondTerm();
    private int thirdTerm = generateThirdTerm();
    private String firstOperator = generateOperator();
    private String secondOperator = generateOperator();
    private int calculationResult = calculateExpression();

    private int generateFirstTerm() {
        return random.nextInt(10);
    }

    private int generateSecondTerm() {
        return random.nextInt(10);
    }

    private int generateThirdTerm() {
        return random.nextInt(10);
    }

    private String generateOperator() {
        String[] operators = {"+", "-", "*", "/"};
        int i = random.nextInt(3);
        return operators[i];
    }

    private int calculateExpression() {
        int firstTerm = getFirstTerm();
        int secondTerm = getSecondTerm();
        int thirdTerm = getThirdTerm();
        String firstOperator = getFirstOperator();
        String secondOperator = getSecondOperator();
        int result = 0;

        switch (firstOperator) {
            case "+":

                switch (secondOperator) {
                    case "+":
                        result = firstTerm + secondTerm + thirdTerm;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        result = firstTerm + secondTerm - thirdTerm;
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        result = firstTerm + secondTerm * thirdTerm;
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        result = firstTerm + secondTerm / thirdTerm;
                        break;
                }

                break;

            case "-":

                switch (secondOperator) {
                    case "+":
                        result = firstTerm - secondTerm + thirdTerm;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        result = firstTerm - secondTerm - thirdTerm;
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        result = firstTerm - secondTerm * thirdTerm;
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        result = firstTerm - secondTerm / thirdTerm;
                        break;
                }

                break;

            case "*":

                switch (secondOperator) {
                    case "+":
                        result = firstTerm * secondTerm + thirdTerm;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        result = firstTerm * secondTerm - thirdTerm;
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        result = firstTerm * secondTerm * thirdTerm;
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        result = firstTerm * secondTerm / thirdTerm;
                        break;
                }

                break;

            case "/":

                switch (secondOperator) {
                    case "+":
                        result = firstTerm / secondTerm + thirdTerm;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        result = firstTerm / secondTerm - thirdTerm;
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        result = firstTerm / secondTerm * thirdTerm;
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        result = firstTerm / secondTerm / thirdTerm;
                        break;
                }

                break;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public int getFirstTerm() {
        return firstTerm;
    }

    public int getSecondTerm() {
        return secondTerm;
    }

    public int getThirdTerm() {
        return thirdTerm;
    }

    public String getFirstOperator() {
        return firstOperator;
    }

    public String getSecondOperator() {
        return secondOperator;
    }


    public int getCalculationResult() {
        return calculationResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться уже реализованными стандартными механизмами, которые умеют вычислять выражения, записанные в строку. Например, можно воспользоваться встроенным движком Javascript. Делается это примерно так:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
System.out.println(engine.eval("100/5*3-2+4"));
```

Это решение гарантирует корректность, так как отлажено миллионами пользователей по всему миру. Но надо быть аккуратным, чтобы в качестве выражения не подсунуть опасный код.

Дополнение: Ещё [здесь](http://www.beyondlinux.com/2011/08/07/3-method-to-evaluate-expressions/) можно глянуть три варианта решения.